# looping over objects javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, object

So recently I learned about using for in loops to loop over objects. We were given this problem to solve regarding a basic cart object that contains name of object and then quantity and price.

```
const cart = {
  "Gold Round Sunglasses": { quantity: 1, priceInCents: 1000 },
  "Pink Bucket Hat": { quantity: 2, priceInCents: 1260 },
};
```

We have to write 2 functions, one that calculates total cost of inventory in cents and the other displays the inventory.

1. The calculateCartTotal function will take in the cart and return a total price, in cents, of everything inside of it.
2. The printCartInventory function will take in the cart and return a string, joined by \n, of the quantity and name of each item.

I was able to the finish question one with ease but am struggling with the 2nd one.

1st function:

```
function calculateCartTotal(cart) {
  let total = 0;
  for(let item in cart){
    const product = cart[item]
    const quantity = product.quantity
    const price = product.priceInCents
    total += quantity * price
  }
  return total
}
```

2nd function:

```
function printCartInventory(cart) {
  let inventory = ""
  for(let item in cart){
    const product = cart[item]
    const quantity = product.quantity
    inventory += `${quantity}x${product}/n`
  }
  return inventory
}
```

When I test the 2nd function the autograder gives this error:

```
expected '2x[object Object]/n1x[object Object]/n1x[object Object]/n3x[object Object]/n' to include '2xCanvas Tote Bag\n1xBlack and White Chuck On Dress\n1xNatural Straw Wide Brim Hat\n3xBlue Stripe Casual Shirt'
```

Comment: `product` is an object. The default `toString` of an object returns `"[object Object]"`. Instead of using the default `toString` output you should print what you actually want from the object (e.g., specific properties, a meaningful representation of a property, etc). There are several ways to do that; the easiest would be something like `${product.quantity}` and so on.

Comment: To me it looks like the names of your product are the keys of the object.  This is a bit gross, but you can fix your code with  `const product = item;` instead of cart[item] (or just use the item variable instead of product)

Comment: Recommend checking out map and reduce. The first function can be rewritten in one line: `const cartTotal = cart.reduce((total, item) => total + (item.quantity * item.priceInCents), 0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the error message, note the part that says `[object Object]`. This is part of your code's output, and should ring a bell. It means your code tries to put an object in a string, instead of a string.

The guilty code is here:

```
inventory += `${quantity}x${product}/n`
```

`product` is not a string, but an object. It is not what you intended to output there. What you want to output is the *name* of the product, which is the *key*, not the value associated with that key. So it should be:

```
inventory += `${quantity}x${item}/n`
```